# Is it possible to have a CUDA kernel with varying number of parameters?

Tags: cuda, arguments

I would like to make a kernel which takes a number of arguments, that is not set. Is this possible?

I guess this does not work? But why?

Comment: varying NUMBER of parameters!

Comment: [This blog](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cplusplus-11-in-cuda-variadic-templates/) may be of interest, as well as the [programming guide reference](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#cpp11-global).

Comment: If you are asking about typical C style vargs, then no. But because kernels support C++ linkage, there are template and name mangling tricks which can be used to instantiate different versions of a kernel with length and different types of argument lists.

Comment: CUDA 7.0 supports C++11 feature variadic templates: http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cplusplus-11-in-cuda-variadic-templates

Comment: Thanks guys! What about CUDA 6.5?

Answer (score 1):

if you are asking about typical C style vargs, then no.

But because kernels support C++ linkage, there are template and name mangling tricks which can be used to instantiate different versions of a kernel with length and different types of argument lists. Note also that CUDA 7.0 introduces C++11 variadic template support.

So there are options to do this, but probably not the  ones you were thinking of when you asked the question.

[This answer assembled from comments and added as a community wiki entry to get the question off the unanswered queue]