# Can I use vararg functions in CUDA device-side code?

Tags: cuda, variadic-functions, gpgpu

I know that we can't write CUDA kernels with a variable number of parameters:

[Is it possible to have a CUDA kernel with varying number of parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30628859/1593077)

(at least not in the C varargs sense; we can use C++ variadic templates.)

But what about non-kernel device-side code, i.e. `__device__` functions? Can these be varargs functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Yes, we can write varargs device-side functions.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

__device__ void foo(const char* str, ...) 
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, str);
    int arg = va_arg(ap, int); // making an assumption here
    printf("str is \"%s\", first va_list argument is %d\n", str, arg);
}
```

This [compiles fine with NVCC](https://godbolt.org/z/DUuwbj) - and works, provided you actually pass a null-terminated string and an `int`. I would not be surprised if CUDA's `printf()` itself were implemented this way.

Comment: For those curious about C++ variadic templates - they work as well without modifications.

Comment: @IGarFieldI: Mentioned that in the question. Also, NVIDIA's documentation and training materials makes that pretty clear.